# Pass variable from one WPF page to another on page switch

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to pass an integer variable from page to page upon switching them with the following code:

```
testPage tp = new testPage();
tp.counter = 3;
this.NavigationService.Navigate(tp);
```

The variable is declared as `public int counter` in its own page - without value. Therefore, according to my tests, it is treated as 0 right after `InitializeComponent()` is called, but is set to 3 by the time events such as button click are executed.

This variable is used to construct the page, namely to create interface objects, so I need it declared right after the page is created or to find a way to delay the page construction, so this variable will have its value set. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you pass the value to the constructor, i.e. `new testPage(3)`?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways

- Provide the property as a static on the App (application) class where both pages can access it as needed.
- Have the other page subscribe to the notify property of the first page and when the value changes, acquire it as such.
- Have the specific properties' setter copy the information to a static on the app page or to a public property on the other page.
- Have the first page pass a reference to itself to a static on the second page and have the second page access the `public` properties of the first page as needed.
- Have both pages share the same VM (view model) with the initial property as such.
- Make sure that both pages have the same datacontext which uses one VM.